How to use jquery after migrating from Rails 6 to 7 with esbuild
I can't use jquery after migrating from Rails 6 to 7. I installed Esbuild. Also I run
yarn add jquery

Add next in application.js
import jquery from "jquery"
window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery

$(function() {
    console.log("hello world")
  })

It's not working(.
But it's working on a clean test project. What is it? I don't understand why this doesn't work after updating the project.
I get an error in the console:ReferenceError: $ is not defined

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
